# Emulate physical keyboard input on windows? On-screen-keyboard isn't enough.

Tags: keyboard, emulation

I have an unusual exploratory test automation task, which relies on detecting keyboard input. (certain trigger words).

However, to automate the task, has proven very difficult, as the input must pass through the keyboard driver it seems. Thus, setting UI automation (like Sikuli, or even ghost mouse) to click on the on-screen keyboard, OR using Sikuli to 'type' or copy/paste text into any windows UI, is not registered.

Any ideas of how to emulate physical keyboard input for the purpose of automation?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an Arduino to emulate a physical keyboard (there are easy to use libraries available). Also, if you use one of the more capable Arduino's with multiple serial ports you can send it what keypresses to emulate through the serial port. The computer will think it is a keyboard like any other. Except you can control it with software.

Of course, this solution assumes you can connect something to the USB port of the test computer.